# matplotlib stacked bar chart does not plot the total values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, python-3.6

I have an array called gender, which stores the number of sales made by males and females. I am trying to create a stacked bar chart of these items but the plot shows the stacked bar chart at 7 on the y axis changing to the next stack which goes up to 14 on the y axis, but should instead go up to 28.

```
    gender = [[7],[14]]
    attributes = ("Male & Female")
    y_pos = np.arange(len(attributes))

    plt.bar(y_pos, gender[0], align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.bar(y_pos, gender[1], align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, attributes)
    plt.ylabel('Volume')
    plt.xlabel('Customer Attributes')
    plt.title('Number of Customer Types')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to obtain with a bar chart made via 2d array. Can you upload a sketch of it? ps. `gender ` is a list of lists, not a 2d-array, moreover I guess you want to define attributes this way `attributes = ("Male", "Female")`

Comment: I corrected the attribute typo - that was a mistake on my part. I was going to use a 2-dimensional array to stack the charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly. But if you want the second bar to sit on top of the first bar, you can achieve that by setting the `bottom` parameter of the second bar to the height of the first, like this:

```
gender = [(7),(14)]
attributes = ["Male & Female"]
y_pos = np.arange(len(attributes))

plt.bar(y_pos, gender[0], align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.bar(y_pos, gender[1], align='center', alpha=0.5, bottom=gender[0])
plt.xticks(y_pos, attributes)
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('Customer Attributes')
plt.title('Number of Customer Types')
plt.show()
```

[image]